# Searching for a tabpage in the tabcontrol C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a tabcontrol in my application. I have a listbox which contains the line no of error and file name and path of the file.On double click i want to add the new tab page.The title of the tabpage should be the name of file from the listbox. If the tabpage with the particular filename already exists then it should not open new tabpage the cursor should point to that page. How to retreive the name of the tabpages .

```
private void lstErrorList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList errorType = new ArrayList();
            if (lstErrorList.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                string error = lstErrorList.SelectedItem.ToString();



                {

                    int result = error.LastIndexOf('\\');
                    string filename = error.Substring(result + 1, error.Length - (result + 1));
                    int pagecount;
                    TabPage tp = new TabPage();
                    pagecount = this.tabControl1.TabPages.Count;
                    for(int tbpagecount=0;tbpagecount<pagecount;tbpagecount++)
                    {
                        pagelist.Add(this.tabControl1.TabPages.ToString());
                    }
                    if (pagelist.Contains(filename))
                    {


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(pagecount, filename);
                        pagecount++;
                    }

                    if (fileNamesList.Count == 0)
                        fileNamesList.Add(filename);
                    else
                    {
                        if (fileNamesList.Contains(filename))
                        {
                            //fileNamesList.Add("");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileNamesList.Add(filename);

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
        bool found = false;
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabControl1.TabPages) {
            if (filename.Equals(tab.Name)) {
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tab;
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if( ! found)
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(filename,filename);
```

Comment: for more speed, add a "break" under the line "found = true;". For this example it isn't very neccassary, but "Many a little makes a mickle." :-)

Answer (score 7):

```
        var tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[filename];
        if (tabPage != null)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage;
        }
        else
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(filename, filename);
        }
```

Comment: It's generally more helpful to prefix your code with an explanation as to what it does and why it works.

Comment: Don't worry @Edy, only you and I know that this is a better answer ;) LOL

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this?

```
        string fileName = "";
        bool isPresent = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabPages.Count; i++)
        {
            if (tabControl1.TabPages[i].Name == filename)
            {
                isPresent = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isPresent)
        {
                tabControl1.TabPages.Add(filename);
        }
        else
        {
                tabControl1.SelectTab(tab.TabIndex);
        }
```

Comment: This will always add a new tab page if the first one is not the one with the given file name and modifying a collection while enumerating it will result in an exception.